# Use emacs as an editor within itself (ansi-term)

Tags: emacs

I'm using `M-x ansi-term` within emacs, and a lot of the tools I use (not only git) are opening editors using `$EDITOR`.

Because running emacs within itself is kind of annoying, I'd like to configure my `$EDITOR` variable such that it opens a new buffer in the emacs session that's running the current instance of `ansi-term`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked before on stackoverflow. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/116570/1731713) is the accepted answer:

> You can attach to an Emacs session through emacsclient. First, start the emacs server with
>
> M-x server-start
>   or add (server-start) to your .emacs. Then,
>
> export VISUAL=emacsclient
>   Edit away.
>
> Note:
>
> 1. The versions of emacs and emacsclient must agree. If you have multiple  versions of Emacs installed, make sure you invoke the version of emacsclient corresponding to the version of Emacs running the server.
> 2. If you start the server in multiple Emacs processes/frames (e.g., because (server-start) is in your .emacs), the buffer will be created in the last frame to start the server.

Comment: Works perfectly! If you're running `ansi-term`, the `$EMACS` variable will be set, so I can figure out which editor to use on my various systems really nicely. Here's [my setup](https://github.com/sfstpala/.dotfiles/commit/ba5dacf0251b47790434bea4f52a205572a55712) for anyone curious.

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo: or you could just use the `ALTERNATE_EDITOR` approach, leave `(server-start)` out of your init file, and let `emacsclient` worry about whether an emacs needs to be started...